# Where is Connection String Located as it relates to Availability Group Listeners?

Tags: sql-server-2012, listener, connection-string, high-availability

I am trying to teach myself about Availability Group Listeners and see that I need to update a "Connection String." I know that I have a connection string in my web.config file on the Web server, but is this where it needs to be updated? Is there somewhere in SQL Server Management Studio where it needs to be updated?

I've updated the connection string there, replacing the server name with the new Availability Group Listener Name that I've created, then updated my database table to replace the server name there with the AG Listener name too. When I update the name in the database table, my records will not open in the GUI where I'm accessing them from a website.

I think this will be a problem because if there is a failover, I'll need to manually update the name of the server for each record of the table to point to the new server location. I figured that if I put in the listener name in place of the server name, this would never need to be updated in the event of a failover.

Any thoughts? I've researched until my brain is mush and really need some help with fully understanding how to get these listeners working. Thanks in advance!